# How to insert date in dd-MM-yyyy format?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", dtp_Date.Value);
```

This code is inserted date in "M/dd/yyyy" format but I want to insert date in dd-MM-yyyy format in ms access database.

Comment: To where? what database you are using?

Comment: The format of date is irrelevant when you are storing in database, You need to format it when you gonna use it e.g in presentation layer (form) to show the date

Comment: database is ms access. I have already tagged and already mentioned @Code

Comment: What is the type of _that_ column you try to insert?

Comment: type is Date/Time @SonerGönül

Comment: @ZoharPeled, my question is different. I haven't found the answer from your given link

Comment: Check my answer. display format is not stored as data in ms access datetime column.

Comment: The _already answered_ link bears no relevance to this question. That said, the answer was given by @Adil above (upvoted).

Answer (score 0):

You can store DateTime in any format in Database.

You require to convert when you want to show it on screem(e.g. View)

For that case use DateTime.TryParseExact:

```
 DateTime dtReturn;

DateTime.TryParseExact(dtp_Date.Value, 'dd-MM-yyyy', CultureInfo.InvarientCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtReturn);
```

Comment: Showing error in line @Neel

Comment: error of overloaded method

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your database field type is 'datetime' and dtp_date is ''String. If so, use the below line of code,

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dtp_Date, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

Comment: This line showing error

Comment: can you Show the line of code that your dtp_Date has defined ?

Comment: Converts the value of current System.DateTime object to its equivalent string representation

Comment: No, I'm asking in your c# code not error message.

Comment: DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dtp_Date, "dd-MM-yyyy", null); a red line of error displaying below code

Answer (score 0):

By assuming that you are inserting into a mysql database, it supports only yyyy-mm-dd format for date. you can format the date while retrieving it from the DB. [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for mysql date functions

Comment: my database in ms access

Answer (score 0):

Datetime in ms access is not stored with it's display format.
In fact, [it's stored as a double:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210276)

> Access stores the Date/Time data type as a double-precision, floating-point number up to 15 decimal places. The integer part of the double-precision number represents the date. The decimal portion represents the time.

You should deal with display format when selecting from the table.